# How do I import the Django DoesNotExist exception?

Tags: django, unit-testing, exception

I'm trying to create a UnitTest to verify that an object has been deleted.

```
from django.utils import unittest
def test_z_Kallie_can_delete_discussion_response(self):
  ...snip...
  self._driver.get("http://localhost:8000/questions/3/want-a-discussion") 
  self.assertRaises(Answer.DoesNotExist, Answer.objects.get(body__exact = '<p>User can reply to discussion.</p>'))
```

I keep getting the error:

```
DoesNotExist: Answer matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: Unrelated to my answer below, is that get() call deleting the Answer in question? If so, that really really should be a DELETE, not a GET.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

You don't need to import it - as you've already correctly written, `DoesNotExist` is a property of the model itself, in this case `Answer`.

Your problem is that you are calling the `get` method - which raises the exception - before it is passed to `assertRaises`. You need to separate the arguments from the callable, as described in the [unittest documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises):

```
self.assertRaises(Answer.DoesNotExist, Answer.objects.get, body__exact='<p>User can reply to discussion.</p>')
```

or better:

```
with self.assertRaises(Answer.DoesNotExist):
    Answer.objects.get(body__exact='<p>User can reply to discussion.</p>')
```

Comment: Good answer, only the first of the above snippets will be caught as invalid syntax (at least by Python 2.7)., should be `self.assertRaises(Answer.DoesNotExist, Answer.objects.get, body__exact = '<p>User can reply to discussion.</p>')` - i.e. with `get`'s arguments added as individual kw args, not inside a `()`.

Comment: Augh, of course! I feel like Dorothy here. I was searching high and low, only to find it was with me all along!

Comment: Python 3.6 / Django 2.2 only the `with` solution worked for me.

Answer (score 211):

You can also import `ObjectDoesNotExist` from `django.core.exceptions`, if you want a generic, model-independent way to catch the exception:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

try:
    SomeModel.objects.get(pk=1)
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    print 'Does Not Exist!'
```

Answer (score 13):

`DoesNotExist` is always a property of the model that does not exist. In this case it would be `Answer.DoesNotExist`.

Answer (score 3):

One thing to watch out for is that the second parameter to `assertRaises` *needs* to be a callable - not just a property.  For instance, I had difficulties with this statement:

```
self.assertRaises(AP.DoesNotExist, self.fma.ap)
```

but this worked fine:

```
self.assertRaises(AP.DoesNotExist, lambda: self.fma.ap)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
self.assertFalse(Answer.objects.filter(body__exact='<p>User...discussion.</p>').exists())
```

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer the question as requested. But it's still a nice solution, offering a different approach to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do such a test.

```
from foo.models import Answer

def test_z_Kallie_can_delete_discussion_response(self):

  ...snip...

  self._driver.get("http://localhost:8000/questions/3/want-a-discussion") 
  try:
      answer = Answer.objects.get(body__exact = '<p>User can reply to discussion.</p>'))      
      self.fail("Should not have reached here! Expected no Answer object. Found %s" % answer
  except Answer.DoesNotExist:
      pass # all is as expected
```